# jqGrid add new column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I found that in jqGrid plugin for JQuery I can add rows dynamically, but can I do the same with columns? If there would be a simple table I'd prefer to do this manually by hands, but jqGrid stores table information in a lot of divs.

Comment: And where your grid will take data for this new column?

Comment: @grizzzly8 it should be empty (the data fields are editable).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is not possible to add a column to the jqGrid dynamically. You have to recreate the whole grid with `colModel` having one column more. If you use separate `colNames`, then the size of the array have to be increased too. You can use [GridDestroy](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) for example to destroy the existing grid. The usage of `jQuery.Remove` or `jQuery.Empty` instead is also possible.

**UPDATED**: It seems to me that [GridUnload](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) is better for your porpose. I created [small demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RecreateGrid.htm) which demonstrate how one can recreate a grid. To be able to use [GridUnload](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) or [GridDestroy](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) you have to verify that you include grid.custom.js in your project (if you use developer version of the jqGrid) or you have checked "Custom" "Additinal methods" on the [jqGrid download](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) page.

**UPDATED 2**: One can use `addColumn` method which can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins) (see `jQuery.jqGrid.addColumn.js`). The method is still in beta phase. One can find some demos which shows how to use the method [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/tree/master/demos) (see `addColumnX.htm` examples).

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find how to use GridDestroy. Can you help me with a small example? `jQuery("#list").jqGrid('GridDestroy');` says that the function is undefined (GridDestroy)

Comment: @Oleg, Thank you very much. Once again you saved my time on jqgrid. +1.

Answer (score 4):

just use

```
$("#gridid").jqGrid('GridUnload');
```

it will unload grid totally and will be ready to load again with new columns and data.

Comment: In the newer version this doesn't work anymore. Use this to unload the jqGrid: $.jgrid.gridUnload('#list');

Answer (score 0):

rownumbers: true,
and
rownumWidth:25(default)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply set the new column model and reload the grid:

```
var newColModel = $("#myGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel").concat({ /* new column attributes */ });
$("#myGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {colModel: newColModel}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```