# jqgrid creation and removal dynamically

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jqgrid

How to remove and add jqgrid dynamically update the jqgrid 
The data in the jqgrid has to be changed of click event. how is it possible to remove or update the existing jqgrid

Comment: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, you should use [GridUnload](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) method. Look at [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232038/jqgrid-add-new-column/4232168#4232168) which include [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RecreateGrid.htm). The demo shows how to remove current grid and on the same place create another grid with another parameters (an additional column). I hope it is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

To select records on the base of year from DataTable in Jqgrid Jquery I have a DataTable and want fiteration in JQGrid