# Clearing jqGrid before loading new data not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Hi there ^_^ I have the following problem:

I have a partial view with a jqGrid on it...and I use `bPopup` to display the partial view as a dialog.

Now there is a list of items on the side of the view. When clicking on an item...the dialog is to be displayed with the table displaying the data relating to that response...

Now the problem is that clicking on subsequent items; the data from the first item clicked is still showed...so I thought that simply calling

```
$("#ListDialogTable").jqGrid("clearGridData");
```

will clear the data and allow me to display the new data...but now when I try to show the dialog in subsequent clicks...only the table headers are shown...no data!

Any ideas and help on this appreciated :)
D

P.s. some code; the method below is called by method `ShowListDialog`

```
function PopulateTable(model) {
    $("#ListDialogTable").jqGrid("clearGridData");
    $("#ListDialogTable").jqGrid({
        jsonReader:
        {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: true,
            cell: "cell",
            id: "id"
        },

        colNames: model.columnN,
        colModel: model.columnM,

        datatype: "jsonstring",
        datastr: model.columnD,

        sortname: model.sortName,
        sortorder: "asc",

        autowidth: true,
        celledit: false,
        gridview: true,
        height: "auto",
        hoverrows: false,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        rowNum: 999,
        viewrecords: true
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post some HTML and javascript code? It is more helpful for us to help you

Comment: code added ^_^ sorry formatting did not include first and last line of code...

Comment: This code is executed each time the dialog needs to be shown...so i dont know if executing it over and over has a bad effect or not...

Comment: To format the code fragment you select your code and click on "{}" element in the toolbar. It do not much more as insert 4 blanks at the beginning of every line and insert empty row before and sometime after the selected text. If you insert the blanks manually you will have the same results.

Answer (score 16):

You can unload the `jqGrid` by using below method:

`jQuery("#tableId").jqGrid("clearGridData");`

Comment: Thanks! Just a comment, use `jQuery("#tableId").jqGrid("clearGridData");` If you want to clear the footer too! :D

Answer (score 3):

You don't posted how the  element with `id="ListDialogTable"`, which you use for the grid, are created. Will be it constructed dynamically or created once and be used many time? Moreover it is not clear whether the `model.columnN` and `model.columnM` can be changed between the calls or not. So I can only guess.

Probably you need use [GridUnload](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) method which allow you **to recreate** the grid including all its elements including the column headers and the pager contain. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RecreateGrid.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232038/jqgrid-add-new-column/4232168#4232168) demonstrate how it works.

Comment: AWESOMENESS!!!Thank you!

$("#ListDialogTable").jqGrid("GridUnload"); did the trick. All I needed to do was call the above line of code in a function bound to the click event of the dialog's close button ^_^

Answer (score 3):

You can use jqgrid's [GridUnload](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods#add_on_grid_methods) method

```
$("#tableId").jqGrid("GridUnload")
```

This will unload the entire grid and will allow you to load new data onto the grid.

Comment: no it doesn't allow you to load new data onto the grid. you need to recreate the grid first. see Oleg's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issues because i am using older version of jqGrid and this is my solution for this:

`jQuery("#grid").clearGridData(true).trigger("reloadGrid");`