# How can i switch between adjacency and nested modes in jqGrid tree grid jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there any way i can switch between adjacency and nested mode of jqGrid tree grid on the fly, i.e. in normal cases i should go for the adjacency mode but in case user applies a filter , i have to show all the rows and this is only possible in nested mode, so i want that i can switch between these two depending on certain conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid create *different* additional hidden columns for TreeGrid in adjacency mode and TreeGrid in nested mode. So to switch to another mode you have to recreate the grid using [GridUnload](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RecreateGrid.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4232168/315935) for example).

What I don't understand is why you can show all rows of TreeGrid only in nested mode. There are in general no such restriction. It could be the problem of your implementation only.