# Showing serial number in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to show serial number as first column in [jqgrid](http://jqgrid.com/).since, database records doesn't has contigous 'ids', I can't use it.

Is there any simple way to accomplish this?

**Update**:
sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {    
    $("#list").jqGrid(
    {
      url:'<%=Url.class_variable_get(:@@baseurl) %>/address_books/show.json',
      datatype:'json',
      mtype:'get',
      colNames:['Id','Name','Email Id','Number'],
      colModel:[
        {name:'address_book_id',index:'address_book_id',sorttype:'int',sortable:true,width:100},
        {name:'name',index:'name',sortable:true,width:300},
        {name:'email',index:'email',sortable:true,width:265},
        {name:'number',index:'number',sorttype:'int',sortable:true,width:300},
      ],
      pager:$('#pager'),
      emptyrecords: "No Records to display",     
      pginput:true,
      pgbuttons:true,
      rowNum:10,
      rowList:[5,10,20,30],
      viewrecords:true,
      sortorder: "desc",
      //multiselect:true,
      loadonce:true,
      gridview:false,
      sortname:'name',
      caption: " Contacts List",
      jsonReader: {
        repeatitems : false,
        cell:"",
        id: "0"
      },
      height: 80
    });

    $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:true},{multipleSearch:true});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This question/answer should contain information on how to redraw the jqgrid based on redefined table data: [jqGrid add new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232038/jqgrid-add-new-column)

Regarding the addition of a you might add a time stamp to each of the records, or even the value of a counter; something like:

```
var recordsSet = [];
$.each(databaseRecords, function(i, record) {
    record.idx = Date.now();
    record._id = i;
    recordSet.push(record);
});

/* code to populate or redraw using update recordSet array jqgrid here */
```

You shoud then be able to assign either the _id field or the idx field (sample property names only) to the index property of your column models in the call to jqgrid.

Comment: currently,when I add new row the page is reloaded & hence grid.since I am getting dta in json from db request,isn't there in-built method jqgrid to do the same?

Comment: Thanks for the code--which of the referenced columns is the serial number? If that data truly doesn't exist then I think adding it through the server might be a better approach. However the question/answer linked in my original answer does address adding columns dynamically to jqgrid.