# Getting Dynamic Columns in JQGrid

Tags: jquery, html, jqgrid

I have a requirement where i need to dynamically increase or decrease Jqgrid column .I have multiple buttons like One,Three,Seven,One Month etc.These buttons denotes days and same i need to add as column names in Jqgrid dynamically.

Here is the pic of the design..

[image: Design layout]

Now as per the picture ,if i click on `current` only one column should be visible ,if click on  `One Day` two columns should be visible and similarly if click on `Month` thirty columns should be dynamically generated.

Here is my JQgrid sample code that i am referring..

```
                grid.jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                data: mydata,
                colNames:['Room No', '12', '13','14','15','16'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'Room No',index:'Room No', width:42, align:'center'},
                    {name:'',index:'', editable:true, align:'center'},
                    {name:'',index:'', editable:true, align:'center'},
                    {name:'',index:'', editable:true,align:'center'},
                    {name:'',index:'', editable:true,align:'center'},
                    {name:'',index:'', sortable:false,align:'center'}
                ],
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little search and I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232038/jqgrid-add-new-column) explaining how to do what you want. And [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RecreateGrid.htm) is a demo adding columns dinamically. Basically, what you have to do is: create a `function` with the data you want for each of your tabs and insert a [click event handler](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to unload the previous set data and call the function for the specific clicked tab to insert new data in the grid.