# Adding a new column to existing JQ GRID

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php, mvcjqgrid

I am working on AbanteCart in which there is use of JQgrid to show the order related information in tabular form. Now , I want to add a new column to this table. The code I have tried till now goes as follow:

```
    $grid_settings['colNames'] = array(
        $this->language->get('column_order'),
        $this->language->get('column_name'),

        $this->language->get('column_status'),
        $this->language->get('column_mode'),//Column Name that I added
        $this->language->get('column_date_added'),
        $this->language->get('column_total'),
    );
    $grid_settings['colModel'] = array(
        array('name' => 'order_id',
            'index' => 'order_id',
            'align' => 'center',),
        array('name' => 'name',
            'index' => 'name',
            'align' => 'center'),
        array('name' => 'status',
            'index' => 'status',
            'align' => 'center',
            'search' => false),
            array('name' => 'payment',//Column data that I added 
            'index' => 'payment',
            'align' => 'center',
            'search' => false),
        array('name' => 'date_added',
            'index' => 'date_added',
            'align' => 'center',
            'search' => false),
        array('name' => 'total',
            'index' => 'total',
            'align' => 'center'),
    );
```

These are the two changes I made up . But it only shows the column name in grid but is not showing related data to that column. Is there something else where I need to change code for showing changes in JQgrid??

name,status,payment etc variables are from database.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jqGrid add new column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232038/jqgrid-add-new-column)

Comment: @Filly I just want to add a new column in the grid. I do not want to add a new grid on some action dynamically. For example, the grid which  used to show me 5 columns before , I want to add a new column and make that grid to show six columns.

Comment: payement should be present in your result set, eg if you're fetching  your results from sql table with select * ... a column `payement` should exist

Comment: @kastormania yes it do exist. I also tried column 'name' instead of 'payment'. But it did not worked. So there is no problem in resultset fetch. Because column 'name' is working fine on grid at its place but when replace 'payment' , it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to understand that jqGrid creates the grid with all internal structures **once**. jqGrid don't provide a method which allows to add new column. So you have the following alternatives:

- use `GridUnload` to "destroy" the grid back to empty `<table>` and recreate the grid with new columns (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4232168/315935))
- create grid with additional **hidden** columns and make hidden column visible using `showCol` when you need to add new column. In the way you will have the same effect as by adding the column.

By the way if you load named property of data in the grid (your JSON input data looks like `{"order_id":"123", "name": "abc" , "status": "OK"...}`) you can define `colModel` as

```
colModel: [
    {name: "c1", key: true, jsonmap: "order_id"},
    {name: "c2", jsonmap: "name"},
    {name: "c3", jsonmap: "status"},
    ...
]
```

using **generic** names `c1` `c2`, `c3`, ... for the columns. In the way you can easy modify the value of `jsonmap` at the runtime. You can set `hidden: true` property or remove it etc. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) shows how to use `beforeProcessing` to modify `colModel` based on the server response. In the way you can makes jqGrid full dynamical.