# How to add extra column in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, webforms, jqgrid

Hi i have this jqgrid in asp.net webform and i successfully load the data but is it possible to add extra column to every row.

here's what my expected result assuming i have File_ID,File_Name, File_age column i need to add i more with a default name open file

```
File_ID|File_Name|File_age|Action
---------------------------------
123    |abc      | 24     |openfile
321    |cba      | 42     |openfile
```

the open file is a link which will call a code behind file.
Row select wont work because i have already a row select that will open the file information

Hope someone help me i'm kida new at this
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to add a column dynamically then you need to rebind the grid again
check the link below.

[jqGrid add new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232038/jqgrid-add-new-column)